# Changing a variable's value with Hotkey

Tags: python, hotkeys

Here, I have a part of my code which detect if `"Esc"` pressed or not. Then change running's value to False and terminate while loop

```
def exit():
    xx = False
    return xx
        
while running:
    add_hotkey("esc",lambda:exit())
    if exit() == False:
        running = False
```

But it doesn't work. In `if` statement, `exit()` starts changing running's value and terminate while loop without pressing any botton. Any Alternative code?

Comment: Calling `exit()` does not change anything's value.  It just returns False.  Did you intend to set `running` to False inside `exit`?  Note that you will need `global running` to do that.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to exit from your program when escape is pressed, provide `sys.exit` as the callback to be called when `esc` is pressed.

```
import sys

while running:
    add_hotkey("esc", sys.exit)
```

Or if you need to do some cleanup code, put it all in a method:

```
def exit():
  print("Exiting...")
  sys.exit()

while running:
    add_hotkey("esc", exit)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason the code doesn't work `running` must have been vague beforehand.
before `while` should you set `runnning = true`